# jQuery "If this image is found add this attribute to mtea tag"

Tags: image, if-statement

I am trying to add an attribute to a meta tag if a certain image is found. This is what I am trying and I can't figure it out.

UPDATE THAT WORKS (90%)

```
    <span id="rateitnow">
    <img src="/images/icons/stars/5stars.gif">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content=" " />
    </span>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict()(function($){
  $('#rateitnow:contains("<img border="0" alt="" style="width:61px;height:12px;" src="/images/icons/stars/5stars.gif">")')
  $("#rateitnow meta").attr("content", "5");
});
</script>
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

TWD

Comment: What does "90%" mean? What is it that is not working? Anyway, I smell you're doing things in not a very nice way. Would you like to explain your goal and context?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = $("#rateitnow > img:first");

    if(img && img.attr('src') == "/images/icons/stars/5stars.gif") {
        $("#rateitnowmeta > meta:first").attr("content", "5");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The above did not populate the content attrib of the meta. I really like how you only added the attribute to the FIRST meta because I do have multi metas there.